# Nuxt3 specify public assets url

Tags: vue.js, vite, nuxt3

So I have built a Nuxt3 App and generated static files using

```
nuxt generate
```

I uploaded the files inside AWS s3 subfolder.
When I load the site, the javascript files loaded correctly.
However, images are not loaded as it is requesting in the root dir of my site instead of the subfolder name.

e.g instead of requesting to mysite.com/mySubFolder/image.jpg it requested to mysite.com/image.jpg

This is my nuxt.config.js

```
 export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        baseURL: '/mySubFolder/,
    },
    ssr: true,
    css: [
        '~/assets/css/main.css',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css',
        '@piwi/component-library/dist/style.css'
    ],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
    modules: [
        [
            '@pinia/nuxt',
            {
                autoImports: ['defineStore', 'acceptHMRUpdate'],
            },
        ],
        '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt',
    ],
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            baseUrl: config.NUXT_API_URL,
        }
    }
})
```